# Angular ngx boostap 2.0.5 datepicker. How to show year only?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

[image]
[image]

I would like show year only.But datepicker have month after cleck selected year number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for [Min-mode](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker?tab=overview#min-mode).

From the [API](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker?tab=api):

```
minMode | Type: BsDatepickerViewMode
        |  Minimum view mode : day, month, or year
```